# How key management happens in both OpenSSL and aescrypt and how the key is stored after encryption?

Tags: encryption, openssl, aes

I am using OpenSSL and aescrypt for encryption and decryption so how key management happens in both OpenSSL,aescrypt and how to save key after encryption?
For example I giving a sample code

`openssl aes-256-cbc -a -salt -in abc.txt -out abc.txt.enc`

`aescrypt -e -p apples abc.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try running the `openssl` command-line, you will see that it will ask for an "encryption password". That password *is* the key; there is no key stored anywhere else.

Looking at OpenSSL's source code (I am here looking at OpenSSL-1.0.2g, file is `apps/enc.c`), it appears that the password is used, along with a random salt, into the [`EVP_BytesToKey()`](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:EVP_BytesToKey(3)) function: that function generates the encryption key (and the IV) from the salt and the password, with a complicated hash-based function. The iteration count is hardcoded to 1 (which, as far as password hashing is concerned, is terrible). The output file (not counting the Base64 encoding added with the `-a` option) starts with a sequence of eight fixed bytes (`53 61 6c 74 65 64 5f 5f`) followed by the salt itself (8 bytes), then the encrypted data. Thus, the salt which was generated randomly is encoded in the file itself, but the password is not stored anywhere else than the brain of the user.

I am not aware of a standard tool called "aescrypt". Google searches show *several* tools with that name, so I cannot know which one you have on your machine. I bet, though, that the general principle is the same: the tool asks for a password, and derives the encryption key from that password.